# Updating EMV Card Parameters

Tags: emv

Does any one know how to update Tag 5F24 (Application Expiry Date) via post issuance command that is through issuer script, and also it will be great help if i can get the list of tags which can be updated using issuer script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not seem programming related and seems to depend on specific EMV (card) application implementations (though no specific implementation was refered in the question).

Answer (score 1):

It is restricted which emv tags can be updated via Put Data script. Lets say that you somehow updated 5F24 via a **security gap**. Then terminals will not approve offline Authentication because 5F24 is important tag and  put on SDA tag list. If extracted 5F24 from Card Certificate is different from the value in card, Offline Authentication will fail.

EMV Tags can be updated with Put Data Script.
MasterCard :

- CDOL1(C7)
- Lower Consecutive Offline Limit (9F14)
- Upper Consecutive Offline Limit (9F23)
- Default APRC Response Code (D6)
- CRM Coutnry Code (C8)
- Application Control(D5)
- AIP(82)
- CIAC-Decline
- CIAC-Default
- CIAC-Online
- LCOTA(CA)
- UCOTA(CB)
- Additional Check Table(D3)
- Currency Conversion Table(D1)

Visa:

- Lower Consecutive Offline Limit (9F58)
- Upper Consecutive Offline Limit (9F59)
- Consecutive Transaction Limit International(9F53)
- Consecutive Transaction Limit Int-Country(9F72)
- Currency Conversion Factor(9F73)
- Cumulative Total Transaction Amount Limit(9F54)
- Cumulative Total Transaction Amount Upper Limit(9F5C)

Answer (score 0):

No. Its Not possible(
Look into: Visa Integrated Circuit Card Specification (VIS).